# Call C# code behind function from programatically created button

Tags: c#, function, webforms, call

In my webform I created button from my code behind:

```
Button btnShowCase = new Button();
btnShowCase.ID = "btnShowCase_" + ticketNumber;
btnShowCase.CssClass = "BtnShowCase";
btnShowCase.Text = "Display";
btnShowCase.OnClientClick = "ShowCase";
```

On client click I want to execute function

```
protected void ShowCase(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Do something
}
```

OnClientClick do not call ShowCase. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
btnShowCase.OnClientClick = "ShowCase";
```

Try

```
btnShowCase.OnClick += ShowCase;
```

`ClientClick` invokes Javascript that runs within the browser; the string argument is the name of a Javascript function.  `Click` causes a postback and invokes a server-side method; the argument is a method that matches the delegate for the event type.

Comment: When tried OnClick, I got error: _button.onclick inaccesible duo to its protection level_. I tried this: 'btnShowCase.Click += new EventHandler(ShowCase);'

Comment: Unfortunately never arrived to Showcase function. in Crome dev tools on client it is appear like this: _href="javascript:__doPostBack('btnShowCase_CAS-17125','')"_

Answer (score -1):

`OnClientClick` is an event handler, and should be set like this:

```
btnShowCase.OnClientClick += "ShowCase";
```

instead of

```
btnShowCase.OnClientClick = "ShowCase";
```